# indicating various properties of html objects

Tags: javascript, html

I am going to set property of html objects.

```
var property1 = 'style.visibility';
var property2 = 'style.display';
var property3 = 'style';
```

I tried following things.

first;

```
1;  object[property1] = 'visible';
2;  object[property2] = 'block';
3;  object[property3].display = 'none';
```

second;

```
1;  object.property1 = 'visible';
2;  object.property2 = 'block';
3;  object.property3.display = 'none';
```

In my case only `first;3;` was working well.
Is there any way to easily indicate the property of html objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create function using `reduce()` to access nested properties.

```js
var property1 = 'style.visibility';
var property2 = 'style.display';
var property3 = 'style';

var obj = {style: {visibility: 1, display: 2}}

function getProp(prop, obj) {
  return prop.split('.').reduce(function(r, e) {
    return r[e]
  }, obj)
}

console.log(getProp(property1, obj))
console.log(getProp(property2, obj))
console.log(getProp(property3, obj))
```

Comment: Thanks, `reduce` will be great support for my programming.